# Aggregate records in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have a table as shown below:

```
document no  |  payment terms | Purchase order no
-------------------------------------------------
1700000000   |  NT30          | 
-------------------------------------------------
1700000000   |                | HPI115881
-------------------------------------------------
1700000000   |                | HPI115881
-------------------------------------------------
1700000002   |  NT30          |
-------------------------------------------------
1700000002   |                | HPI163799
-------------------------------------------------
1700000003   |  NT30          |
-------------------------------------------------
1700000003   |                | HPI160969
-------------------------------------------------
1700000004   |  NT30          |
-------------------------------------------------
1700000004   |                | HPI13641
```

As you can see, for the same **document no**, I have 2 records - one with **payment terms** and other with **Purchase order no**.

What I want is to have just one line for all document numbers with all three columns populated like below:

```
document no   payment terms    Purchase order no
1700000000       NT30              HPI115881
```

Any help on this will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What did you tried? Show your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a suggestion, You can achieve by following query

```
select
    document_no,
    group_concat(distinct 'payment terms') as 'payment terms',
    group_concat(distinct 'Purchase order no') as 'Purchase order no'
from table
group by document_no
```

Group by document_no will display distinct of document_no, same time you can group_concat so it will skip  the null value and display the expected data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a faster method, but you can solve your problem in 2 different way (at least):

Method 1 (all in memory):

- select all records where payment terms is not empty (or null)
- select all records where Purchase order no is not empty (or null)
- update all the records from the first selection
- delete all the records from the second

Method 2:

- use MySQL stored procedure to split the table in two (here some help [How to split table into multiple tables using SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648480/how-to-split-table-into-multiple-tables-using-sql))
- use MySQL stored procedure to merge two table based on the same index (document no)

Comment: Thanks Dabr. How do I merge two tables based on same index? I have already done step 1 of your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks Dabr. I am planning to use method 2. How do I merge two tables based on same index? I have already done step 1 of your suggestion. Also, can you provide some code snippet to do this as u mentioned in method 1.

Comment: here a hint https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/429140/combine-two-tables-value-into-one-table-value-and